# reemplazar valores NULL por el valor anterior

Tags: sql

buenas tardes Maestros

tengo un problema, tengo el siguiente Query,

```
        ; WITH CTE AS ( 
        SELECT 
        CAMPO as PRODUCTO, 
        START_DATETIME AS FECHA, 
        RECIBOS, 
        DESPACHOS, 
        STOCK, 
        DIAS
    
    FROM [dbo].[V_ECP_MPV4_N6_POLYMEROS_BODEGA]
    )
SELECT *
FROM CTE 
OPTION(RECOMPILE)
```

el tema es que en la columna DIAS, tengo unos valores, no en toda las filas, necesito que ese valor se repita cuando sea encuentre un null, y luego si encuentra el valor, lo repita, así sucesivamente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si nos colocas un ejemplo. de como quisieras que quede la consulta.

Comment: ok, ya habia pegado una imagen, pero no se que paso, aqui la pego nuevamente

Answer (score 1):

Una forma de "arrastrar" el valor de la columna en la última fila que no es null es valerse de una consulta recursiva, dónde tomamos como base las filas para las que dicha columna es no nula y luego vamos iterando por las filas siguientes utilizando el valor encontrado para cada una de estas.

Para mostrarte un ejemplo, he hecho primero un *CTE* que contiene la información que muestras en tu ejemplo, llamada como tu tabla base y con los mismos nombres de campos, de manera que puedas copiar y pegar para probarla rápidamente, y luego eliminar esta parte para utilizar la tabla real que tiene los datos.

Dentro de mi secuencia de *CTE*'s, el segundo, llamado `Base` es básicamente el que tu llamas `CTE` en tu ejemplo.

A partir de allí, hago un nuevo *CTE* llamado `ReCTE` (de **Re**cursivo) en donde, primero, tomo todas las filas cuya columna `dias` es no nula, y en la parte recursiva voy seleccionando los registros de los *días consecutivos siguientes* del mismo producto, siempre del *CTE* `base`, pero en lugar de devolver el campo `dias` de este, devuelvo el campo `dias` de la fila del día anterior (que ya se encuentra en el resultado recursivo), que es ir realizando la sustitución tal como comenté al inicio.

El código probablemente lo expresa mejor que las palabras:

```
; WITH 
V_ECP_MPV4_N6_POLYMEROS_BODEGA as (
select *
  from (values ('ARROZ', cast('20200101' as date), 4932900, 90000, 4842900, 54)
             , ('ARROZ', '20200102', 0,     0, 4842900, null)
             , ('ARROZ', '20200103', 0,     0, 4842900, null)
             , ('ARROZ', '20200104', 0,     0, 4842900, null)
             , ('ARROZ', '20200105', 0,     0, 4842900, null)
             , ('ARROZ', '20200106', 0, 60000, 4782900, 80)
             , ('ARROZ', '20200107', 0,     0, 4782900, null)
             , ('ARROZ', '20200108', 0,     0, 4782900, null)
             , ('ARROZ', '20200109', 0, 30000, 4582900, 158)
             , ('ARROZ', '20200110', 0,     0, 4582900, null)
             , ('ARROZ', '20200111', 0,     0, 4582900, null)
             , ('ARROZ', '20200112', 0,     0, 4582900, null)
             , ('ARROZ', '20200113', 0,     0, 4582900, null)
             , ('ARROZ', '20200114', 0,     0, 4582900, null)
       ) q(campo, start_datetime, recibos, despachos, stock, dias)
)
,
Base AS ( 
select   CAMPO as PRODUCTO
       , START_DATETIME AS FECHA
       , RECIBOS
       , DESPACHOS
       , STOCK
       , DIAS
  from [V_ECP_MPV4_N6_POLYMEROS_BODEGA]
)
,
ReCTE as (
select   a.PRODUCTO
       , a.FECHA
       , a.RECIBOS
       , a.DESPACHOS
       , a.STOCK
       , a.DIAS
  from Base a
 where a.DIAS is not null
union all
select   a.PRODUCTO
       , a.FECHA
       , a.RECIBOS
       , a.DESPACHOS
       , a.STOCK
       , b.DIAS
  from Base a
       inner join ReCTE b on a.PRODUCTO = b.PRODUCTO and a.FECHA = dateadd(day, 1, b.FECHA)
 where a.DIAS is null
)
SELECT *
FROM ReCTE
order by PRODUCTO, FECHA
```

El resultado devuelto es:

```
PRODUCTO    FECHA      RECIBOS DESPACHOS  STOCK   DIAS
ARROZ      2020-01-01  4932900 90000      4842900 54
ARROZ      2020-01-02  0       0          4842900 54
ARROZ      2020-01-03  0       0          4842900 54
ARROZ      2020-01-04  0       0          4842900 54
ARROZ      2020-01-05  0       0          4842900 54
ARROZ      2020-01-06  0       60000      4782900 80
ARROZ      2020-01-07  0       0          4782900 80
ARROZ      2020-01-08  0       0          4782900 80
ARROZ      2020-01-09  0       30000      4582900 158
ARROZ      2020-01-10  0       0          4582900 158
ARROZ      2020-01-11  0       0          4582900 158
ARROZ      2020-01-12  0       0          4582900 158
ARROZ      2020-01-13  0       0          4582900 158
ARROZ      2020-01-14  0       0          4582900 158
```

### Advertencia

En base a lo que he visto, estoy asumiendo que la tabla tiene siempre **fechas consecutivas** para cada uno de los *productos*. Si este no es el caso, entonces ya te tocará adaptar la consulta. (Una posible solución es utilizar algún otro campo que sea secuencial o numerar las columnas en el primer CTE).

Debes tener presente que, realizar una consulta recursiva será más costoso, en CPU y memoria, que una consulta *normal*. Mi recomendación es utilizar esta solución si el tamaño del conjunto de datos y la carga que genera en el servidor la hacen aceptable.

Comment: muchas gracias Maestro, ahora, me fue de mucha utilidad,

Comment: una pregunta, jachuate, lo que pasa es que me sale error y no ejecuta la consulta, pues estoy llamando un promedio de 70 millones de registros, y me sale este error arning: el orden de combinación se ha aplicado porque se utiliza una sugerencia de combinación local. Mensaje 530, Nivel 16, Estado 1, Línea 6 La declaración finalizó. La recursión máxima 100 se ha agotado antes de la finalización de la declaración.

Comment: Si, con ese número de registros me temo que la solución debiera ir por otro lado. ¿Las fechas siempre son consecutivas?

Comment: @sadidleonardocastillamonter, he publicado una nueva respuesta donde no tiro de la recursividad para lograr el resultado. No he editado esta, pues también resuelve el problema y puede ser de utilidad para quienes lleguen aquí en el futuro buscando soluciones.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes construir la solución, sin utilizar un *CTE* recursivo sino un simple join, realizando los siguientes pasos (para lo cual me valgo de *CTE's*.

1. El CTE llamado `V_ECP_MPV4_N6_POLYMEROS_BODEGA` tiene los datos que has puesto como entrada en el ejemplo, con el mismo nombre de campos de la tabla subyacente.
2. El CTE `Base` recupera la información de la tabla subyacente y, además, agrega una columna donde se van *numerando* los registros para cada `producto`, de 1 a N, en orden por fecha.

   Esta columna, llamada `NumeroFilaProducto` es la base de la solución, aunque no es lo ideal porque SQL server no tendrá un índice. La he incluido, dado que no me queda claro si las fechas pueden repetirse para un producto o cual es la manera completa de obtener los registros en el orden deseado. Lo ideal, para una tabla subyacente que tiene muchos registros, es utilizar un campo del que SQL server pueda tirar de índices para construir la solución. Un candidato es la fecha, siempre que haya garantía que `CAMPO` y `START_DATETIME` son únicos, idealmente con un constraint `UNIQUE` o un índice `UNIQUE`.
3. El *CTE* `BaseDias` recupera las filas de `base` que tienen un valor no nulo en la columna `DIAS` y utiliza las funciones de ventana `lag()` y `lead()` para obtener el número de fila de la fila anterior y la siguiente en el resultado.
4. Finalmente, el *CTE* `AsignaDias` construye el resultado final. Para ello, primero recupera las filas del *CTE* `BaseDias`, con su respectivo valor de días.

   Luego, le une el resultado del join que, para cada registro de `BaseDias`, obtien los registros de `Base` que están entre la fila actual y la fila siguiente, y a estos les coloca el valor de `DIAS` obtenido de `BaseDias`.

   Finalmente, aunque los datos no muestran ese caso, le añade todos los registros que puedan ser anteriores al primer registro que tiene valor en la columna `DIAS` para cada producto, dejando `NULL` en la columna `DIAS`.

```
; WITH 
V_ECP_MPV4_N6_POLYMEROS_BODEGA as (
select *
  from (values ('ARROZ', cast('20200101' as date), 4932900, 90000, 4842900, 54)
             , ('ARROZ', '20200102', 0,     0, 4842900, null)
             , ('ARROZ', '20200103', 0,     0, 4842900, null)
             , ('ARROZ', '20200104', 0,     0, 4842900, null)
             , ('ARROZ', '20200105', 0,     0, 4842900, null)
             , ('ARROZ', '20200106', 0, 60000, 4782900, 80)
             , ('ARROZ', '20200107', 0,     0, 4782900, null)
             , ('ARROZ', '20200108', 0,     0, 4782900, null)
             , ('ARROZ', '20200109', 0, 30000, 4582900, 158)
             , ('ARROZ', '20200110', 0,     0, 4582900, null)
             , ('ARROZ', '20200111', 0,     0, 4582900, null)
             , ('ARROZ', '20200112', 0,     0, 4582900, null)
             , ('ARROZ', '20200113', 0,     0, 4582900, null)
             , ('ARROZ', '20200114', 0,     0, 4582900, null)
       ) q(campo, start_datetime, recibos, despachos, stock, dias)
)
,
Base AS ( 
select   row_number() over (partition by CAMPO order by START_DATETIME) NumeroFilaProducto
       , CAMPO as PRODUCTO
       , START_DATETIME AS FECHA
       , RECIBOS
       , DESPACHOS
       , STOCK
       , DIAS
  from [V_ECP_MPV4_N6_POLYMEROS_BODEGA]
)
,
BaseDias as (
select   NumeroFilaProducto
       , lag(NumeroFilaProducto) over (partition by producto order by NumeroFilaProducto) NumeroFilaAnterior
       , lead(NumeroFilaProducto) over (partition by producto order by NumeroFilaProducto) NumeroFilaSiguiente
       , producto
       , fecha
       , recibos
       , despachos
       , stock
       , dias
  from Base
 where dias is not null
)
,
AsignaDias as (
select   a.NumeroFilaProducto
       , a.PRODUCTO
       , a.FECHA
       , a.recibos
       , a.despachos
       , a.stock
       , A.DIAS
  from BaseDias a
union all
select   b.NumeroFilaProducto
       , b.PRODUCTO
       , b.fecha
       , b.recibos
       , b.despachos
       , b.stock
       , a.dias
  from BaseDias a
       inner join base b on b.producto = a.producto 
                        and b.NumeroFilaProducto > a.NumeroFilaProducto 
                        and b.NumeroFilaProducto < coalesce(a.NumeroFilaSiguiente, 999999999)
union all
select   b.NumeroFilaProducto
       , b.PRODUCTO
       , b.fecha
       , b.recibos
       , b.despachos
       , b.stock
       , b.dias
  from BaseDias a
       inner join base b on b.producto = a.producto 
                        and b.NumeroFilaProducto < a.NumeroFilaProducto 
 where a.NumeroFilaAnterior is null
)
select   a.PRODUCTO 
       , a.FECHA
       , a.recibos
       , a.despachos
       , a.stock
       , a.dias
       , a.NumeroFilaProducto
  from AsignaDias a
 order by a.Producto, a.NumeroFilaProducto
```

```
PRODUCTO FECHA      recibos     despachos   stock       dias
-------- ---------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
ARROZ    2020-01-01 4932900     90000       4842900     54
ARROZ    2020-01-02 0           0           4842900     54
ARROZ    2020-01-03 0           0           4842900     54
ARROZ    2020-01-04 0           0           4842900     54
ARROZ    2020-01-05 0           0           4842900     54
ARROZ    2020-01-06 0           60000       4782900     80
ARROZ    2020-01-07 0           0           4782900     80
ARROZ    2020-01-08 0           0           4782900     80
ARROZ    2020-01-09 0           30000       4582900     158
ARROZ    2020-01-10 0           0           4582900     158
ARROZ    2020-01-11 0           0           4582900     158
ARROZ    2020-01-12 0           0           4582900     158
ARROZ    2020-01-13 0           0           4582900     158
ARROZ    2020-01-14 0           0           4582900     158

(14 rows affected)
```

## Sobre el desempeño

Como ya he dicho antes, dado que el conjunto de datos que se quiere manejar en esta consulta es grande (en un comentario se ha dicho 70 millones de registros), lo ideal sería utilizar un campo que esté almacenado en la tabla y para el que se pueda tirar de índices para realizar los *join* de las tablas. Si esto no es posible, se puede almacenar el resultado del primer *CTE* en una tabla temporal, crear un índice sobre las columnas `PRODUCTO` Y `NumeroFilaProducto`, y finalmente hacer el resto del proceso.

Ambos ejercicios quedan para el AP.